# Is there any case law which prove that two natural person sign a contract on two different day

Tags: contract-law, internet

Is there any case study of a natural two person can be signed a contract on different days

Comment: I have to think that there's something else going on here: why would anyone think it significant that a contract wasn't signed by the parties at the same time?  Is someone questioning whether there was adequate communication to establish an agreement, or something like that?

Comment: The question isn't clear.  Contracts are dated.  You don't need "case law" to determine whether people signed on different dates or not, the dates written on the contract are evidence of that.  So what is your actual confusion/question?

Comment: Actually I need to prove that if the contract done by 2natural person on different days so I need to prove with case study

Answer (score 2):

### Contracts are often signed on different days

Often, the signing of a document is the formalisation of a contract that already exists - that is, the offer and acceptance happened sometime in the past (the date of the contract), and perhaps even some work has already been done.

Other times, particularly in real estate or finance contracts, the contract comes into effect when the last person signs.